# angular onChanges highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have a chart that should change the displayed data if I choose another person. When you try to display in `console.log(this.pieChart)` everything works fine. But at the same time, the chart itself is not redrawn after another person is selected and he has completely different data for the chart.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

hours.ts:

```
  hours: Hour[];
  pieChart = [];
  pieCategoryChart = [];
  loading: boolean = false;

  @Input('people_id') people_id: number;

  ngUnsubscribe: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private _hoursService: HoursService,
    private _toast: ToastrService
  ) {
    cdr.detach();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.ngUnsubscribe = this._hoursService.fetch(this.people_id).subscribe((hours) => {
      this.hours = hours;
      this.pieChart = this.hours.map(hour => ({
        name: hour.activity,
        y: hour.hours,
        color: hour.color
      }));
      this.loading = false;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }, error => {
      this._toast.error(error.message);
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
  }
```

I even made a data refresh button on the chart, but it doesn't want to be redrawn. How to work with highcharts correctly?

hours.html:

```
<div *ngIf="hours">
    <button (click)="load()">Test</button>
    <app-pie [data]="pieChart"></app-pie>
</div>
```

people.html:

```
 <app-hours *ngIf="people?.person_id" [people_id]="people.person_id"></app-hours>
```

pie.html:

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions"
    style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
</highcharts-chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that you are looking for a way to dynamically update your chart using the `highcharts-angular` wrapper.

If so to make it work all you have to do is to update the data of your `chartOptions` that you are passing to the `highcharts-chart` component and toggle the `updateFlag`. I can see that your pie.html is missing the `[(update)]` input, so that's probably the reason why it is not working correctly.

Here you can find a live example of the optimal way to update your chart:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update

You can find more information including live examples in the highcharts-angular docs that can be found here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

```html
  <highcharts-chart 
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [(update)]="updateFlag"
    >

  <button (click)="onClick()">Update data</button>
```

```js
export class AppComponent  {
   Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  updateFlag = false;

  data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  chartOptions: Options = {
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        data: this.data
      }
    ]
  }

  onClick() {
    this.chartOptions.title =  {
      text: 'updated'
    };

    this.chartOptions.series = [{
        type: 'line',
        data: this.data.reverse()
    }
  ]

    this.updateFlag = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working wherever you will call it. In this example it is working after the button is pressed but you could call it on the OnInit as well. Take a look at the other demo I prepared for you, as you can see there I am updating the chart after 3 seconds using the `ngOnInit` method. Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-xcz2tf?file=src/app/app.component.ts